# Pivotal Cloud Foundry - Spring Cloud Services

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I am trying to push the company app into Pivotal Cloud Foundry. The app should be bound with service registry. I didn't do any changes in `application.yml` file. I had have service-registry service in my Pivotal apps manager console. After I pushed my company app into PCF and binded with service-registry service. I did restage my company app. The app is not registered in the service registry console.

> 2016-06-06T11:25:36.72+0530 [APP/0] OUT Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://p-spring-cloud-services.uaa.******.com/oauth/token":sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to fin
>   d valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.securit
>   y.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

and

> 2016-06-06T05:49:35.000+00:00 [APP] OUT 2016-06-06 05:49:35.668 ERROR 22 --- [pool-5-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : DiscoveryClient_COMPANY/https://p-spring-cloud-services.uaa.******.com/oauth/token:****** - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Error requesting access token.

How to solve these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of problem is ssl certification for PCF. I think you are not uploaded ssl certificate to your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Your PCF instance should have valid root certificates of your apps installed at their side and vice versa....